# Typeahead shows results as undefined

Tags: javascript, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead

I am trying to use typeahead to display google suggestions.

The Ajax call works fine and data is returned properly:

Before executing **return process(data);**
data contains an array of strings that start with "w".

> data = ["walmart", "weather", "wells fargo", "worldstarhiphop",
>   "walgreens", "wikipedia", "white pages", "world cup", "webmd",
>   "weather radar"]

However the suggestions displayed show "undefined" instead of real words.
Any idea what I am missing here? Thanks.

[image]

```
    <input type="text" class="typeahead" placeholder="Search">


    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    },
    {
        source: function (query, process) {
            $.getJSON("Home/Suggest", { query: query }, function (data) {
                return process(data);
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update:

After some research, I found an answer to my question and will post it here, if someone needs it.

The trick is - the "process" callback function expects the results in a format:

[{value: "string1"}, {value: "string2"}, {value: "string3"}]

and not just an array of strings.

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead(
{ hint: true, highlight: true, minLength: 1 }, // options
{
    source: function (query, process) { // source dataset, data = array of strings
        $.getJSON('Home/Suggest', { query: query }, function (data) {
            //data=["string1", "string2", "string3"]
            //process callback function needs it 
            //in a format [{value: "string1"}, {value: "string2"}, {value: "string3"}]
            var output = $.map(data, function (string) { return { value: string }; });
            process(output);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. There were also old version in typeahead documentation.

Comment: I am getting the same error and I'm following [this](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#the-basics) example.  My source is substringMatcher(states) and states is an array.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jharding/9458744#file-the-basics-html has a fix for the broken initial example http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Comment: Yes that first example is broken,`matches.push(str);` should be `matches.push({value: str});`