# Trying to use typeahead to autocomplete acts-as-taggable-on tag list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-typeahead, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a page on my website with a form that allows users to add tags to an item.  I want to incorporate typeahead so that when a user starts typing a tag in the input box, a dropdown list appears with existing tags that match the string.  I think I can accomplish this with the [basic example](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#the-basics) but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my show page with the script:

```
<div id="add-tag-form">
  <%= form_tag add_tag_path, id: "custom-tag",
        class: "form-group",
        autocomplete: "off",
        remote:true
  do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :tag, nil, placeholder: 'Add tag', class: "form-control typeahead", id: 'add-tag' %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Add' %>
    <span id = "tag-block" class="help-block"></span>
  <% end %>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
      return function findMatches(q, cb) {
        var matches, substringRegex;

      // an array that will be populated with substring matches
      matches = [];

      // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
      substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

      // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
      // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
      $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
        if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
          matches.push(str);
        }
      });

      cb(matches);
    };
  };

  var tags = Tag.all.pluck(:name);

  $('#add-tag-form .typeahead').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'tags',
    source: substringMatcher(tags)
  });
});
</script>
```

In the console I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token :` which is pointing to the :name in the line `var tags = Tag.all.pluck(:name);`.  My thoughts are the ruby isn't being recognized within the script tags but I could be wrong.  What is the correct way to do this?

Also, do I need the `$(document).ready` line at the start of the script?

Comment: Try `var tags = <%= Tag.all.pluck(:name) %>`

Comment: Now I am getting a `unexpected token &` error.  Following the link in console it looks like that line is interpreted as `var tags = [&quot;et&quot;, &quot;non&quot;, &quot;neque&quot;, &quot;molestiae&quot;...]`.  et, non, neque, and molestiae are all tags so I think we're on the right.  Maybe its something with the `pluck` method.  I need a way to make an array of all tag names.

Comment: Fixed this using raw at the begininng `var tags = <%= raw Tag.all.pluck(:name) %>`.  The typeahead list is populating with undefined repeated over and over.

Comment: Cool! I believe `var tags = <%= Tag.all.pluck(:name).to_json.html_safe %>` also working for that.

Comment: Any ideas why I am getting undefined in typeahead dropdown?  I found this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442052/typeahead-shows-results-as-undefined but I am copying the example from the twitter website almost exactly.

Comment: What's the result inside your JS console of `console.log(typeof tags)`?

Comment: typeof tags is object

Comment: Wierd. It should work. Ok, what the result of `console.log(tags)`?

Comment: It returns the correct array of strings.

Comment: `<%= text_field_tag :tag, nil, placeholder: 'Add tag', class: "form-control typeahead", id: 'add-tag' %>` here you specify the ID name to be `#add-tag` but inside the JS, you write `$('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({`. Your JS should be `$('#add-tag .typeahead').typeahead({`.

Comment: I actually caught that before but forgot to change it in my question.  Still getting the same error.

Comment: `var tags` still unchanged. Make it `var tags = <%= Tag.all.pluck(:name).to_json.html_safe %>`.

Comment: I actually tried changing that to be an array of strings and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Turns out I was using the [bootstrap-typeahead-rails](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-typeahead-rails) gem which is different than the [twitter-typeahead-rails](https://github.com/yourabi/twitter-typeahead-rails) gem.  The former uses typeahead v0.10.5, the latter 0.11.1.  I switched to the newer gem and now its working.  Unfortunately the typeahead search that I had working beautifully on another part of my site is now broken.